# Recover an accidentally deleted note of a Gmail contact

Tags: gmail, google-contacts

I've just deleted the note field of one of my Gmail contacts which contains very critical information.

Is it possible to recover it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can restore your contacts to any point in the last 30 days.

From [Restore Contacts](https://support.google.com/mail/answer/1069522):

> 1. Click **Gmail** at the top-left corner of your Gmail page, then choose **Contacts**.
> 2. From the **More actions** drop-down menu, choose **Restore contacts**.
> 3. Choose the time you'd like to revert your contacts list to (e.g. 10 minutes ago, one hour ago, one week ago, etc). We suggest that you also make a note of the time that you restore your contacts, in case you'd like to return to where you started.
> 4. Click **Restore**. You'll see a confirmation at the top of the screen when the rollback is complete.

You might want to export your current contacts before you do this.